# React Typescript - Working with multiple checkboxes in a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, jsx

I have a usecase where I need to work with multiple checkboxes in a list

Only one check box can be selected at a time

Eg. If I toogle on `Checkbox 1` and then **click** on `Checkbox 2` - then I need to **toogle off** `Checkbox 1` as I toogle **on** `Checkbox 2`

Please check the code at [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-booth-xfb1b6?file=/src/App.tsx)

I have added the parent component for context, I hope this will be fixable.

Please help me fix this

Thank you

Comment: Standard would be to use radio, not checkbox, for this. It's better for accessibility. Is there a good reason to use checkbox?

Comment: That said, this is one component with one checkbox. If you have a parent, that's where the responsibility would be for unchecking the rest of the checkboxes.

Comment: Radio buttons need to be used in pairs correct. So I'm trying to have only one checkbox

Comment: I can post my parent component if you would be so kind and help me fix this

Comment: No, radio buttons with the same name are part of a group, per [html standard](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp). Then the browser takes care of the exclusivity of checked states. But if the way the component is split makes this a PITA, post your parent and we can take a look.

Comment: Parent component posted

Comment: Why do both the parent and the child take the same type as props? Does whatever this represents have a type? `InterdentalBrush.regular`

Comment: Also, I can't find CircleIcon or Orange - which lib are you using for these?

Comment: ProductList (child) --> Products (sub-parent) --> Another component (Parent)
I'm passing an click event from the child to the top parent

Comment: import CircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Circle';
import CheckCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckCircle';

Comment: import { ReactComponent as Orange } from 'assets/images/tool/brushes/orange.svg';

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you had a demo  =)  So where does this come from? `InterdentalBrush.regular.map((brush, index)` - keeping in mind that i'm making a codesandbox so I can decide how to pass up the checked property. If you already have that let me know. If you already have types defined, posting them helps a lot too.

Comment: This is a json file with some data values

Comment: Also have a types file with property fields

Comment: ```export type InterdentalBrush = {
  id?: string;
  brush_size?: number;
  color_name?: string;
  color_hex?: string;
  isChecked?: boolean;
  onEmit: (data: InterdentalBrush) => void;
};

export interface InterdentalBrushProps extends InterdentalBrush {}```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is kinda hard to do without good demo code all in one spot or a codesandbox, so here's a much smaller demo that works using much smaller and simpler objects. If you check a box, the rest become unchecked. You can see how I bind the state in the child component, and the parent updates the state accordingly. You can pop this into a code sandbox with no dependencies other than react and typescript.

Full demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-exclusive-lf2vz9

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const AnimalArray = [
  {
    name: "Bear",
    selected: false
  },
  {
    name: "Cat",
    selected: false
  },
  {
    name: "Dog",
    selected: true
  }
];

type Animal = {
  name: string;
  selected: boolean;
};

type Animals = {
  animalList: Array<Animal>;
};

type AnimalProps = {
  animal: Animal;
  onSelectedChanged: (animal: Animal) => void;
};

const AnimalComponent = (props: AnimalProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={props.animal.name} readOnly={true} />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={props.animal.selected}
        onChange={(el) => {
          props.onSelectedChanged({
            name: props.animal.name,
            selected: el.target.checked
          });
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const AnimalListComponent = (props: Animals) => {
  // this could be further pushed up state instead of (or in addition to) being handled here
  const [animals, setAnimals] = useState<Animal[]>(props.animalList);

  const onChange = (currentAnimal: Animal) => {
    setAnimals((currentState) =>
      currentState.map((i: Animal) =>
        i.name === currentAnimal.name
          ? {
              ...i,
              selected: currentAnimal.selected
            }
          : {
              ...i,
              selected: currentAnimal.selected ? false : i.selected
            }
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p>list</p>
      {animals.map((animal, index) => (
        <AnimalComponent
          key={index}
          onSelectedChanged={onChange}
          animal={animal}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [animals] = useState<Animals>({ animalList: AnimalArray });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AnimalListComponent animalList={animals.animalList} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I will create a codesandbox with my code and after I will post it so that you can test it and update the code

Comment: I have created the codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-booth-xfb1b6?file=/src/App.tsx - Please check it

Comment: @Jaser So, a fork. https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-alex-qm9mzt?file=/src/Products.tsx

Comment: @Jaser  I basically used the same logic as I posted here in the answer, and applied it to your (forked) example